# Jmeter - Passing specific JSON response to HTTP request dynamically

Tags: json, jmeter, httprequest, httpresponse, beanshell

I am having a specific requirement in Jmeter(2.13) where i need to pass two parameters multiple times dynamically as id and parentObjectApiName

```
{
            "id":"SomeNumber",
            "parentObjectApiName":"SomeName"
         },
         {
            "id":"SomeNumber",
            "parentObjectApiName":"SomeName"
         },

}
```

Which i will be getting from a response as :

```
{
    "detailMap": {
      "RootNumber": [
        {
          "id": "SomeNumber",
          "properties": {

          },
          "isDeleted": false,
          "version": "2017-11-20T08:13:30+00:00",
          "referenceId": null,
          "parentObjectApiName": "SomeName"
        },
        {
          "id": "SomeNumber",
          "properties": {

          },
          "isDeleted": false,
          "version": "2017-04-21T15:40:10.742+00:00",
          "referenceId": null,
          "parentObjectApiName": "SomeName"
        },
        {
        :
        },
      ]
    }
    "state": {
      "errorDetails": []
    }
  }
```

Is there any workaround for the above requirement by using beanshell in Jmeter(2.13).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement can be achieved by following the steps below.

1. Add "JSON Extractor" to the request where the response contains the parameters which you want to pass in next request.(Image-1)
2. JSON Extractor configuration(Image-2)

Keeping the JSON Extractor as it is, Add "Beanshell PostProcessor" to the request and keep the following part of code and try. Your desired id & parentObjectApiName will be stored in variable "json". You can call it in your next request as ${json}

```
import java.io.file;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.jmeter.services.fileserver;

StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
Random random = new Random();
int max = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("id_matchNr"));
for(int i=1;i<=max;i++)
{
output.append("{");
output.append("\"id\":\"" + vars.get("id_"+i) + "\",\"parentObjectApiName\":" + vars.get("parentObjectApiName_"+i));
output.append("}").append( "," );
}
String withoutLastComma = output.substring( 0, output.length( ) - ",".length( ) );
vars.put("json", withoutLastComma.toString());
```

[Image-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnhNX.png)

[Image-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQTpg.png)

Comment: Thank you,
I appreciate your answer however for the above solution i need to pass {"id":"${id_1}", "parentObjectApiName":"${parentObjectApiName_1}"} and so on for whatever each id and parentObjectApiName
Is there any mechanism to pass this as a whole in request whatever i am getting in response.
Also i have configuration criteria - Need to get this on Jmeter 2.13

Comment: From my understanding, 
If 5 id & parentObjectApiName's found in response, then there's a possibility where we can send them 5 ids in 5 requests. Does this full fill your requirment? If your are ok with this one, let me know, will post the detailed solution.

Comment: Thank you,
 If 5 id & parentObjectApiName's found in response.
I need to pass them in JSON array as :
[
            "id":"SomeNumber1",
            "parentObjectApiName":"SomeName1"
         },
         {
            "id":"SomeNumber2",
            "parentObjectApiName":"SomeName2"
         }
]

Comment: I have edited my answer, please try that. I hope it would work fine.

Comment: One query for the above solution i need to pass {"${id_1}":"","${id_2}":""} for the same kind of scenario.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Try replacing this line "output.append("\"id\":\"" + vars.get("id_"+i) + "\",\"parentObjectApiName\":" + vars.get("parentObjectApiName_"+i));"
Replace with: "output.append("\"id\":\"" + vars.get("id_"+i));"

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that [since JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for any scripting in JMeter. [Groovy has much better performance than Beanshell does](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black), moreover [Groovy has built-in JSON support](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html).

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON
2. Make sure you have `groovy` selected in the "Language" dropdown and `Cache compiled script if available` box ticked
3. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
   import groovy.json.JsonOutput
   import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
   import groovy.json.internal.LazyMap

   def text = prev.getResponseDataAsString()
   log.info('Original response: ' + text)
   def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(text)
   def data = new ArrayList()
   json.detailMap.RootNumber.each { rootNumber ->
       def map = new LazyMap()
       map.put("id", rootNumber.id)
       map.put("parentObjectApiName", rootNumber.parentObjectApiName)
       data.add(map)
   }
   vars.put('json',JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(data)))
   log.info('Generated json: ' + vars.get('json'))
   ```

The above code will generate the following JSON:

```
[
    {
        "id": "SomeNumber",
        "parentObjectApiName": "SomeName"
    },
    {
        "id": "SomeOtherNumber",
        "parentObjectApiName": "SomeOtherName"
    }
]
```

[image: JMeter Groovy Generate JSON]

You will be able to access it as `${json}` where required (i.e. in next [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler "Body Data" tab)

Comment: Thank you,
Above solution is working however i am getting json as empty